# How do I use FDR in this situation?

Tags: false-discovery-rate, familywise-error

Firstly, I am not a statistician so apologies if attempt of a solution is ridiculous.

I am trying to come up with an algorithm that estimates a vector $v$ thats contaminated with noise

Suppose we have vector $v$ (which has entries $1, \ldots, l$) of $0's$ and $1's$. I want this function to be independent of how $v$ is distributed so no inference of its distribution should be used, but for now lets assume its uniform (also each entry of the vector is independent)

Now I make $n$ copies of this vector and then add Gaussian noise with mean 0 and variance 1 to each copy (independently) lets call them $x_1, \ldots x_n$. I want to use $x_1 \ldots x_n$ to try and recover $v$

I want to try and estimate the original using false discovery rate but I'm not quite sure how I would apply it to this situation

Suggest I'm trying to estimate the $i$th entry of $v$. According to wikipedia (BH procedure) I would have a collection of null hypothesis, I'm a little unconfident in thinking they're

$H_1 =$ the $i$th entry is $0$ with added Gaussian noise of mean $0$

$H_2 = $ the $i$th entry is $1$ with added Gaussian noise of mean $0$

Then wikipedia (Benjamini–Hochberg procedure) says I should have some $p$-values, but now I'm a little lost, p-values corresponding to what data? My best guess is that they're

$p_1$ is the probability of getting data at least as extreme as $\{x_i(1), \ldots,x_i(l)\}$ under the assumption of $H_1$

$p_2$ is the probability of getting data at least as extreme as $\{x_i(1), \ldots,x_i(l)\}$ under the assumption of $H_2$

(I think I would use a t-test to calculate these p-values with dgrees of freedom $n-1$?)

Now I am meant to order them, for simplicity lets assume they're already ordered

Lets set false discovery rate $\alpha = 0.05$.

Suppose $k=1$ is the largest $k$ such that $P_k \leq \frac km \alpha = 0.025k$ and so then I reject $H_1$. Is it now a fair to say that my best guess at $v(i)$ is that it is $1$?

What should I infer if all or none $k$ are such that $P_k \leq \frac km \alpha$

Does this look correct to you?

I appreciate any feedback

Thanks

Comment: "I am trying to come up with an algorithm that estimates a vector  thats contaminated with noise" -- sounds like a statistician to me!

Comment: I held off writing a more complete answer because it's a little unclear to me what your data and analysis goal are. Let $v$ be a deterministic mapping $v: \{1,\dots,l\} \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$, and you observe $v + N$ where $N \sim Gaussian(0, 1)$ and want to recover $v$, correct? And for each element $i$ of $v$ you conduct an hypothesis test of $H_0:\ v_i = 0$ and $H_A:\ v_i = 1$?

Comment: @ssdecontrol Yes that's correct $B$ is a vector known to contain $0$'s and $1$'s and I observe $B+G$, I want to estimate $B$ using FDR. It's part of a supervised side project I am working on and my supervisor advised me to use FDR. I, like you, am struggling to work out how it can be applied to help me in this situation :(

Comment: I edited more detail into my comment

Comment: Correct, I can observe $v+N$, and I observe it $n$ independent times. Yes that's right, they're the hypothesis's I came up with (I couldn't think of any others)

Comment: Why are you trying to use FDR? Is there a particular reason? There are other, more established, methods of matrix recovery.

Comment: @Chris yes and I've used many other methods to do so. I've basically been given a list of methods to experiment with, this was one of them

Comment: @Henry, Ah, I just read your comment above; my apologies.

Comment: @Henry, is $n$ potentially large in size, or is it limited?

Comment: @ChrisC I have had some success with $n \approx 10$ with other methods, and what I've been using while trying to come up with something using FDR

Comment: @HBeel did you ask your supervisor for clarification? Maybe you can mention how most FDR control algorithms aren't really equipped for this problem

Comment: @ssdecontrol I shall discuss it with him, I agree, FDR isn't the best technique here. Either way it was my first time using FDR and a learnt a lot trying to use it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my shot, it might be incorrect, so hopefully more people will chime in.

Given a $g\times1$ vector $v$ : {$1, ..., g$}  $\to$ {$1, 0$}, and an error vector $e$ ~ $Z(0,1)$, creating $n$ copies of $v+e$ results in a $g \times n$ matrix named $V$.

We want to recover $v$, knowing the distribution of $e$.  Each row $i$ of $V$ either has true $\mu = 0$ or $\mu = 1$, which we can assess by a simple $Z$ test for $\hat{\mu} = 0$ because we know the distribution of the noise.

We are interested solely in true differences larger than 0, so we decide to do a one-tailed Z test.  This makes:

$H_0:$ $\mu_i = 0$

$H_1:$ $\mu_i > 0$

Setting $\alpha = 0.05$, critical $z = 1.6449$ for a one tailed $Z$ test.

[image: Power calculation]

Computing a $Z$ test P value for each row $V_i$ gives us a $g \times 1$ vector of P values, of which we must correct for multiple testing through FDR.

Because we set $\alpha = 0.05$, the chance of truly accepting the null is 0.95 for one test, and 0.95$^n$ for $n$ uncorrelated tests.  Obviously this must be corrected for.  One method would be Bonferroni, another would be FDR.  Bonferonni correction controls family wise error rate, wheras FDR controls the false discovery rate.

Ordering your P values (but obviously maintaining their index values) and allowing for false discovery rate = 0.05, you would declare a test a significant result if $P_i < \frac{i}{g} \alpha$. This would mean that the effect overcomes the multiplicity (with 5% error).  If you have no values with $P_i < \frac{i}{g} \alpha$, it means that none of your values have been succesfully recovered.

However, the original one tailed $Z$ test only has $\beta - 1 = 0.26$ at $\alpha = 0.05$, so only $\approx$ 26% of your true 1 values can be recovered.  If $g$ is small, then perhaps noise overwhelmed signal in all your cases.

There are definitely better ways, but I hope this helped a little bit.

Comment: The difficulty I have with this answer, and indeed with the whole problem, is that I can't seem to think of how one might tighten $H_1$ from a range (including an infinity of values we don't care about) to a point, the single value we do care about. The BH procedure, in my understanding, is fundamentally "Fisherian" in that is works by manipulating the magnitude of p values, while the problem is fundamentally "Neymanian-Pearsonian."

Comment: It is an explicit comparison of two well-defined hypothesis that are complements in an arbitrary space, rather than the comparison of an explicit null hypothesis with an implied alternative in Euclidean space. Since $\alpha$ is a concept from the NP paradigm, it should be possible to control the FDR without appealing to p values that depend monotonously on an unbounded test statistic. That is, it should be possible to tighten up $H_1$ from a range to a point, and still apply some kind of FDR control. But I don't know how any of the FDR procedures I know (eg BH) can do this

Comment: (+1 for the nice answer)

Comment: @ssdecontrol, I completely agree with everything you mentioned, and I find myself having the same problem with my answer. I am completely sure that $H_1$ should not be a range, however, I was also at a loss of how to formulate it.  The insistence on using FDR in this problem makes it significantly more difficult. Thank you for the upvote, by the way.

Comment: It also seems that having an alternative hypothesis that is "too large" biases the analysis. What about $H_0: P_i \leq 0.5$ and $H_1: P_i > 0.5$? Then you can go full Fisherian and say "further from 0.5 is greater evidence in that direction." It's a hack but it works in this case. Actually I bet this is a general principle: as long as you can embed your hypotheses in a metric space such that they are linearly separable, you can define your null hypothesis in terms of a cutoff and construct a test statistic accordingly. I think the machine learning camp already does this

Comment: Thanks for your answer (although I must admit I haven't quite got from start to finish working through it yet), and also your input @ssdecontrol . I agree it's an awkward setting to work with.

Comment: @ChrisC I have implemented what I had hoped for. I didn't really understand what the pValues were corresponding too and how to order them. Your answer is excellent, thanks!

Comment: @ssdecontrol, that's really interesting, and I'll have to try it out and see if it helps the power! Thanks for the really interesting discussion! HBeel, I'm glad we were of help; hope everything works out for you!